# php upload script

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload

i am trying to insert data in a 'songs' column of a table with name same as the current session variable username. but it is giving following error
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."('songs') VALUES(\"$_FILES["file"]["name"]\")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."('songs') VALUES(\"".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."\")");
```

The quotes in the variable were causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['username']."(songs) VALUES('\\" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "\\')"
```

- remove single quote around the *table name* `song`
- wrap the value of `song` with single
- use single quote in `$_FILES['file']['name']`
- escape `\` with `\`